# css grid help making columns 2 on 1

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

i am stuck with css problem.
I have elementor blog template i need to make on 1 / 2 / 1 columns.
See attach on photo. I made with :nth-child(3) & :nth-child(4) to be 50%, but i can not make them on same line.

I find other way to make it with: `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` but they are space on right side i cannot remove.
Please help for resolve this problem :)

[image][image]

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you want?

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.grid__item {
    background-color: lightblue;
    padding: 10vh 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.grid__item:nth-child(1) {
    grid-row: 1/2;
    grid-column: 2/4;
}

.grid__item:nth-child(2) {
    grid-column: 2/3;
}
.grid__item:nth-child(4) {
    grid-column: 2/4;
}
```

```html
<section class="grid">
    <div class="grid__item">1</div>
    <div class="grid__item">2</div>
    <div class="grid__item">3</div>
    <div class="grid__item">4</div>
</section>
```

Comment: @asing macan
Thank you!
this is helpful and working
Only second item and third width are not same.
If i make second child width to be 1/2 and third 1/2 they not on same row
Can this be fixed?

Comment: if you want to change width based on the Grid, you have to play CSS here "grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);" and if you want to change it custom, you have to create a new CSS for 2 and 3.